# Hello, how can i load two path with different django modal forms?

Tags: html, django

i was trying django modals form . i create a model called "devices" i got one view working which makes the device form load up on the index device page. After that created another model called "Customers" and made forms and view for it but, when i load the files from URL it only loads the first Form which is devices and not the customer. so when i click the create customer button; device model is loaded in the form and if put the customer path at first in in my URL it loads fine but in "create device" button in device html; the form loads up with customer modal form

this is Path Fil

examples/URL

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from examples.views import login_view,register_view,logout_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Home.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('home/', views.Home.as_view(), name='home'),

    # Device URL

    path('device', views.DeviceIndex.as_view(), name='indexDevice'),
    path('create/', views.DeviceCreateView.as_view(), name='create_device'),
    path('update/<int:pk>', views.DeviceUpdateView.as_view(), name='update_device'),
    path('read/<int:pk>', views.DeviceReadView.as_view(), name='read_device'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>', views.DeviceDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_device'),

      # Customer URL
    path('customer', views.CustomerIndex.as_view(), name='indexCustomer'),
    path('create/', views.CustomerCreateView.as_view(), name='create_customer'),
    path('update/<int:pk>', views.CustomerUpdateView.as_view(), name='update_customer'),
    path('read/<int:pk>', views.CustomerReadView.as_view(), name='read_customer'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>', views.CustomerDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_customer'),
```

Setup/URL

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', include('examples.urls')),
]
```

indexCusctomer

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% include "_modal.html" %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">




<div class="container mt-3">
   -->
   {% include 'navbar.html' %}

  <center>
    <h2>
      <strong style="color: #c2c1c1;">Customers</strong>
    </h2>
  </center>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 mb-3">
      <button class="create-customer work" type="button" name="button">
        <span class="fa fa-plus mr-2"></span>Create Customer</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 mb-3">
      {% if customers %}
      <table class="table">
        <thead class="thstyle">
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center" scope="col">#</th>
            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Name</th>
            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Email</th>
            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Contact</th>
            <th class="text-center" scope="col">User Name</th>
            <th class="text-center" scope="col">State</th>
            <th class="text-center" scope="col">City</th>

            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Read / Update / Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for customer in customers %}
          <tr class="trstyle">
            <th class="text-center" scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
            <td class="text-center">{{ customer.customer_name }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ customer.email }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ customer.contact }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ customer.users_name }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ customer.get_state_type_display }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ customer.get_city_type_display }}</td>

            <td class="text-center">
              <button type="button" class="read-customer btn btn-sm btn-primary"
                data-id="{% url 'read_customer' customer.pk %}">
                <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
              </button>
              <button type="button" class="update-customer btn btn-sm btn-primary"
                data-id="{% url 'update_customer' customer.pk %}">
                <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
              </button>
              <button type="button" class="delete-customer btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                data-id="{% url 'delete_customer' customer.pk %}">
                <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
              </button>

            </td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      {% else %}
      <p class="no-customers text-primary">No customer added yet.</p>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}

{% block extrascripts %}
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {

    // Create book button
    $(".create-customer").modalForm({ formURL: "{% url 'create_customer' %}", modalID: "#create-modal" });

    // Update book buttons
    $(".update-customer").each(function () {
      $(this).modalForm({ formURL: $(this).data('id') });
    });

    // Read book buttons
    $(".read-customer").each(function () {
      $(this).modalForm({ formURL: $(this).data('id') });
    });

    // Delete book buttons
    $(".delete-customer").each(function () {
      $(this).modalForm({ formURL: $(this).data('id') });
    })

    // Hide message
    $(".alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
      $(".alert").slideUp(500);
    });

  });

  function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "200px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "200px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#2a3747";
  }
</script>


{% endblock extrascripts %}
</html>
```

indexDevice

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% include "_modal.html" %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">




<div class="container mt-3">
   {% include 'navbar.html' %}

  <center>
    <h2>
      <strong style="color: #c2c1c1;">DEVICES</strong>
    </h2>
  </center>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 mb-3">
      <button class="create-device work" type="button" name="button">
        <span class="fa fa-plus mr-2"></span>Create device</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 mb-3">
      {% if devices %}
      <table class="table">
        <thead class="thstyle">
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center" scope="col">#</th>
            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Name</th>
            <th class="text-center" scope="col">IP Address</th>
            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Type</th>
            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Publication date</th>

            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Read / Update / Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for device in devices %}
          <tr class="trstyle">
            <th class="text-center" scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
            <td class="text-center">{{ device.device_name }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ device.IP_address }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ device.get_device_type_display }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ device.publication_date }}</td>

            <td class="text-center">
              <button type="button" class="read-device btn btn-sm btn-primary"
                data-id="{% url 'read_device' device.pk %}">
                <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
              </button>
              <button type="button" class="update-device btn btn-sm btn-primary"
                data-id="{% url 'update_device' device.pk %}">
                <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
              </button>
              <button type="button" class="delete-device btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                data-id="{% url 'delete_device' device.pk %}">
                <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
              </button>

            </td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      {% else %}
      <p class="no-devices text-primary">No devices added yet.</p>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}

{% block extrascripts %}
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {

    // Create book button
    $(".create-device").modalForm({ formURL: "{% url 'create_device' %}", modalID: "#create-modal" });

    // Update book buttons
    $(".update-device").each(function () {
      $(this).modalForm({ formURL: $(this).data('id') });
    });

    // Read book buttons
    $(".read-device").each(function () {
      $(this).modalForm({ formURL: $(this).data('id') });
    });

    // Delete book buttons
    $(".delete-device").each(function () {
      $(this).modalForm({ formURL: $(this).data('id') });
    })

    // Hide message
    $(".alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
      $(".alert").slideUp(500);
    });

  });

  function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "200px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "200px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#2a3747";
  }
</script>


{% endblock extrascripts %}
</html>
```

examples/view.py

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views import generic
from bootstrap_modal_forms.generic import (BSModalCreateView,
                                           BSModalUpdateView,
                                           BSModalReadView,
                                           BSModalDeleteView,
                                           BSModalLoginView)
from .forms import UserLoginForm,UserRegisterForm                                          
from .forms import DeviceForm,CustomerForm
from .models import Device,Customer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import (authenticate, get_user_model, login, logout)


class Home(generic.ListView):
    context_object_name = 'title'
    template_name = 'home.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return 'WELCOME TO MANNAI COMMAND CENTER'



# view Device
class DeviceIndex(generic.ListView):
    model = Device
    context_object_name = 'devices'
    template_name = 'indexDevice.html'


class DeviceCreateView(BSModalCreateView):
    template_name = 'devices/create_device.html'
    form_class = DeviceForm
    success_message = 'Success: Device was created.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('indexDevice')


class DeviceUpdateView(BSModalUpdateView):
    model = Device
    template_name = 'devices/update_device.html'
    form_class = DeviceForm
    success_message = 'Success: Device was updated.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('indexDevice')


class DeviceReadView(BSModalReadView):
    model = Device
    template_name = 'devices/read_device.html'


class DeviceDeleteView(BSModalDeleteView):
    model = Device
    template_name = 'devices/delete_device.html'
    success_message = 'Success: Device was deleted.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('indexDevice')





# view customer
class CustomerIndex(generic.ListView):
    model = Customer
    context_object_name = 'customers'
    template_name = 'indexCustomer.html'

class CustomerCreateView(BSModalCreateView):
    template_name = 'customers/create_customer.html'
    form_class = CustomerForm
    success_message = 'Success: Customer was created.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('indexCustomer')


class CustomerUpdateView(BSModalUpdateView):
    model = Customer
    template_name = 'customers/update_customer.html'
    form_class = CustomerForm
    success_message = 'Success: Customer was updated.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('indexCustomer')


class CustomerReadView(BSModalReadView):
    model = Customer
    template_name = 'customers/read_customer.html'


class CustomerDeleteView(BSModalDeleteView):
    model = Customer
    template_name = 'customers/delete_customer.html'
    success_message = 'Success: Customer was deleted.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('indexCustomer')


def login_view(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next')
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        if next:
            return redirect(next)
        return redirect('/index')

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, "authentication/login.html", context)

def register_view(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next')
    form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        new_user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=password)
        login(request, new_user)
        if next:
            return redirect(next)
        return redirect('/login/')

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, "authentication/signup.html", context)


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/home/')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
path('device/', views.DeviceIndex.as_view(), name='indexDevice'),
path('update/<int:pk>/', views.DeviceUpdateView.as_view(), name='update_device'),
```

add trailing slash in your urls wherever it is not there.